# Why these dynamically inserted HTML elements aren't display with proper alignment

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I add few input fields & labels in bootstrap.
Then i add  jQuery/javascript code to add & remove dynamically features.The script works fine.
But these dynamically inserted HTML elements are not displaying with proper alignment.
Please check image given below
[image]

I think,i put some elements in wrong position.
please suggest me about bringing  proper alignment back.
Here is the source code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <title>Bootstrap Add/Remove</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="container">
         <form class="form-inline" role="form">
            <div class="form-group" id="parent_div">
               <div class="row form-group child_div">
                  <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-3">
                     <label for="form-input-col-xs-2" class="wb-inv">Other Job Position:</label>
                     <div class="input-group" style="">
                        <select class="form-control " id="employeetype" onchange="updateText('')">
                           <option value="" disabled="" selected="">Select Job Type</option>
                           <option value="10">1</option>
                           <option value="10">2</option>
                           <option value="10">3</option>
                        </select>
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-3">
                     <label for="form-input-col-xs-3" class="wb-inv">Date:</label>
                     <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-input-col-xs-3" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" />
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></i></span>
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-3">
                     <label for="form-input-col-xs-3" class="wb-inv">Amount:</label>
                     <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-input-col-xs-3" placeholder=".00" />
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-usd"></i></span>          
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group ">
                     <div class="input-group">
                        <input class="btn btn-danger deleteButton" type="button" value="-" />       
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <label for="day" class="col-xs-2 control-label"></label>
            <input class="btn btn-success " type="button" id="create_button" value="+" />
         </form>
      </div>
      <script  type="text/javascript">     
         $('#create_button').click(function() {
           var html = $('.child_div:first').parent().html();
           $(html).insertBefore(this);
         });
         
         $(document).on("click", ".deleteButton", function() {
           $(this).closest('.child_div').remove();
         });    
          
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

please let me know if any further information is required.
Thanks :)

Comment: can you make fiddle for this?

Comment: sorry i never used fiddle.i did try to add my local file to fiddle.But i am not seeing any option to do so.thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here's the complete html with some style to fix the alignment:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <title>Bootstrap Add/Remove</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <style>
        div.child_div:first-child {
            margin-top: 0px;
            padding-top: 0px;
        }
        div.child_div {
            width: 615px;
        }
        div.job-position {
            width: 220px;
        }
        div.job-type {
            width: 180px;
        }
        div.job-amount {
            width: 180px;
        }
        div.form-group {
            padding-top: 25px;
        }
        input#create_button {
            margin-top: 50px;
        }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="container">
         <form class="form-inline" role="form">
            <div class="form-group" id="parent_div">
               <div class="row form-group child_div">
                  <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-3 job-position">
                     <label for="form-input-col-xs-2" class="wb-inv">Other Job Position:</label>
                     <div class="input-group" style="">
                        <select class="form-control " id="employeetype" onchange="updateText('')">
                           <option value="" disabled="" selected="">Select Job Type</option>
                           <option value="10">1</option>
                           <option value="10">2</option>
                           <option value="10">3</option>
                        </select>
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-3 job-date">
                     <label for="form-input-col-xs-3" class="wb-inv">Date:</label>
                     <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-input-col-xs-3" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" />
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></i></span>
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-3 job-amount">
                     <label for="form-input-col-xs-3" class="wb-inv">Amount:</label>
                     <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-input-col-xs-3" placeholder=".00" />
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-usd"></i></span>          
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group ">
                     <div class="input-group">
                        <input class="btn btn-danger deleteButton" type="button" value="-" />       
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <input class="btn btn-success " type="button" id="create_button" value="+" />
         </form>
      </div>
      <script  type="text/javascript">     
         $('#create_button').click(function() {
           var html = $('.child_div:first').parent().html();
           $(html).insertBefore(this);
         });

         $(document).on("click", ".deleteButton", function() {
           $(this).closest('.child_div').remove();
         });    

      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

You still have two problems though:

1. The page allows you to delete the last item.  The code should handle this situation.  The problem is, if the last item is deleted, you can't create a new one from the first item.
2. Load the page, click add, remove the first item, then click add again, you get multiple green buttons.  You should fix that.

Comment: yes it worked fine.Both of your comment was very helpful.Thanks @Will

Answer (score 1):

Remove this line:

```
<label for="day" class="col-xs-2 control-label"></label>
```

It doesn't seem to have any purpose, yet it causes the mis-alignment.

Another issue you have is the red button is aligned to the top with the other divs.  Add padding-top to that div should push it down to line up with the other fields and buttons.

Comment: Thanks. it works with remove (-) sign. but add(+) is still have some gap space.

Comment: change the width of the div with id of parent_div.  This width is pushing the green button to the right.  You can also align the button the same way with padding.

Comment: i just resize grid for  <div class="form-group col-md-8" id="parent_div"> but still the gap space is there.thanks

Answer (score 1):

You wrote:

```
$('#create_button').click(function() {
   var html = $('.child_div:first').parent().html();
   $(html).insertBefore(this);
});
```

That takes the contents of child-div's parent (i.e. the content of #parent-div) and appends it before **this**. In the case of the click handler - which is assigned to #create_button - this is the **button itself**. If you use insertBefore(this) in that context you are inserting your content between the label and the button.

```
<label for="day" class="col-xs-2 control-label"></label>
    <!-- You just inserted a code block here! -->
<input class="btn btn-success " type="button" id="create_button" value="+" />
```

I'm pretty sure that's not what you intended to do.

P.S. be careful about copying code this way. The elements you're copying have IDs attached, but IDs should be unique across any given document.

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
      <title>Bootstrap Add/Remove</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js">   </script>
   </head>
 <body>
  <div class="container">
     <form class="form-inline" role="form">
        <div class="col-lg-2">
            <label for="day" class="col-xs-2 control-label"></label>
            <input class="btn btn-success " type="button" id="create_button" value="+" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-10">
           <div class="form-group" id="parent_div ">
              <div class="row child_div col-lg-12">
                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                       <label for="form-input-col-xs-2" class="wb-inv">Other Job Position:</label>
                       <div class="input-group" style="">
                          <select class="form-control " id="employeetype" onchange="updateText('')">
                             <option value="" disabled="" selected="">Select Job Type</option>
                             <option value="10">1</option>
                             <option value="10">2</option>
                             <option value="10">3</option>
                          </select>
                       </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                       <label for="form-input col-xs-3" class="wb-inv">Date:</label>
                       <div class="input-group">
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-input-col-xs-3" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" />
                          <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></i></span>
                       </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3">
                       <label for="form-input-col-xs-3" class="wb-inv">Amount:</label>
                       <div class="input-group">
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-input-col-xs-3" placeholder=".00" />
                          <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-usd"></i></span>          
                       </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-1">
                    <div class="input-group">
                       <input class="btn btn-danger deleteButton" type="button" value="-" />       
                    </div>
                    </div>
             </div>
          </div>
        </div>


     </form>
  </div>
  <script  type="text/javascript">   
     var html = $('.form-group').html();  
     $('#create_button').on("click", function() {
       $('.form-group').append(html);
     });

     $(document).on("click", ".deleteButton", function() {
       $(this).closest('.child_div').remove();
     });    

  </script>
```

Comment: almost near.But middle input (Date) shows little bit upper position.thanks